# Хочу создать лимитированный запрос в SQL SERVER

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server, sql-server-2017

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                      'SERVER=LAPTOP-Q5MJ2UNM;'
                      'Database=School;'
                      )

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Students LIMIT 5')

myresult = cursor.fetchall()

for result in myresult:
    print(myresult)
```

Выбивает ошибку:

> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Students LIMIT 5;')
>   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "5". (102) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В T-SQL нет `LIMIT`, используйте [TOP](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql):

```
cursor.execute('SELECT TOP(5) * FROM Students')
```